# How to disable BottomTab display on one of the screens

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have here such navigation using `BottomTab`

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import Home from './Home'
import Second from './Second'
import Other from './Other'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{
        showLabel: true,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          position: 'absolute',
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          elevation: 0,
        }
      }}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Second" component={Second}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Other" component={Other} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I would like to:

- On the `Home` and `Other` screen **BottomTab** is visible normally
- On the `Second` screen, **BottomBar** disappears (here you can only click back to return to another screen with **BottomTab** visible)

How to get this effect? (Camera turns on on this screen so I don't want BottomBar to be visible))

EDIT:

It should work as in the picture

[image]

In this situation (middle button) we can only undo

Answer (score 0):

Create a component as a group of screens where `bottom tab` is not required. Provide this component to `TabNavigator`. [See here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/)

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{
        showLabel: true,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          position: 'absolute',
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          elevation: 0,
        }
      }}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Second" component={SecondScreen}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Other" component={Other} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Second screen component

```
const SecondScreen = () => (
      <Stack.Navigator>
       <Stack.Screen name="Second" component={Second}
    </Stack.Navigator>
)
```

Comment: Nothing is change. Bottom Bar is visible

Comment: I added image how it should work. What is in the documentation is a little different situation